# Generate all permutation of a string in recursion in java

Tags: java, string, recursion, permutation

I would like to know how to create all permutation of a given string in a recursive way.

Lets say that `String a = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstxyz";`.

I would like to generate a string of length 5 (for example) from `a` using **recursion**,

meaning:

- aaaaa
- aaaab
- aaaba
- aaaca
- zabfg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, do you have a question?

Comment: This is the question...How to create the described permutations using recursion only.

Comment: Along with that solution, only print out results of length 5

Comment: This solution is not what I'm looking for. I cannot use any for loops in this task. All other solutions that I saw in this website use for loops.

Answer (score 1):

First, just store all the unique characters using a HashMap or so, then transfer them to a List, which we will call chars, for ease of use.

Your recursive method is building on a string. When that string reaches length 5, you are done, and you want to keep it. You can return the string or simply store it in a global list.

In this case, assume your list is called permutations.

```
void generatePermutation(String current) {
    if (current.length == 5) {
        permutations.add(current);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.size(); i++) {
            generatePermutation(current + chars.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not allowed to use for loop, only recursion..

Comment: And I have to generate all possible permutations of length 5. In the example I gave there are 5^26 permutations.

Comment: It is impossible to do without a for loop.